# AngularJS: on load issue

Tags: angularjs, spring

Getting error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep]` in Angularjs service loading.

Following is the `service.js`

```js
App.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['Service', function(Service) {  
    var myHttpInterceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
            if (!Service.isAnonymus) {
                config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = Service.token;
            }
            return config;
        }
    };
    return myHttpInterceptor;
}]);
App.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
****Solution**:**



App.factory('csrfResponseInterceptor', [function () {
    return{
        response: function(response){
            console.log(response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN'));
            return response;
        }
    }
}]);

App.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            response: function(response) {
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = response.headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
                return response;
            }
        }    
    });
}]);
```